# If and or in jQuery function, is it possible to combine?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have these two that I want to combine. If a link is clicked or if a div is visible. Can these two be in the same statement?

```
if ($("#foo").click(function() || $("#bar").is(":visible")) {
    some code here...
}
```

Comment: please google first for syntax

Comment: They are just examples, not my whole code :)

Comment: SO is not just for you. What about future visitors? This is not useful to them.

Comment: you could post an example without syntax errors at least...

Comment: @Satpal Just tell him what he could have done better. I'm sure even you were a beginner at some point.

Comment: I have a working code already. I only need the advice If I can combine these two into one statement. Otherwise I'm going to have to repeat the code.

Comment: @jgillich, My comment was in response to OP dull comment _They are just examples, not my whole code :)_

Comment: @user3496563, We are here to help. As of now its more of guess work _what exactly you want?_

Comment: I modified the code a bit to make sense of what I'm trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following would do the trick!

```
$("#foo").click(function() {
  clickFunction();
}

if($("#bar").is(":visible")) {
  // #bar is visible
  clickFunction();
}

function clickFunction() {
  /* the function code */
}
```

What I have done is, that I have created a common function for the event. Then you'll check for the condition. Either the hyperlink is clicked or the div is visible, it would execute the code in the function.

#### Note

Please note that checking for a visible div, without any click is not going to work. You can use another event, or a function.

```
<button>Check visibility</button>
```

jQuery code is like following to check the event for the button.

```
$('button').click(function () {
  // here check for visiblity, because without event you can't do that.
  if($('#bar').is(':visible')) {
     now do the code!
  }
}
```

Comment: This is not what I'm looking for. If the div "bar" is visible then the same things must happen as when the link "foo" is clicked.

Comment: Thanks, this is a cool way to do it and I don't have to repeat the code twice!

Answer (score 1):

If I got your comment, this is what you want:

```
function doSomething () {
    // ...
}

if ($("#bar").is(":visible")) {
    doSomething();
}

$("#foo").click(doSomething);
```